# Ethernet Switch with Mux

Tags: ethernet, multiplexer

I'm attempting to design a circuit that is capable of simulating an Ethernet disconnection event for a piece of test equipment. There doesn't appear to be any reference material that uses back-to-back magnetics, and I'm concerned about signaling voltages going negative (and therefore, out of range of what the mux can handle), so I'm using 49.9K pullups on each TR pair. I've also connected the center taps to +3V3, which I'm not sure is 100% correct. Can anybody provide me with some feedback, hints, and critique, here?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Please add magjack type, preferably a link to data sheet. Also between which two devices the connection is? What is the test device? Is it gigabit or only 100Mbps connection? Why disconnection needs to be simulated?

Comment: In my view There is no need for magnetics. The structured cabling supports typically 3-4 passive connections in a signal chain, for 100BASE-TX, this is to allow punchdown blocks and patch panels to be 802.3 compliant (in most cases). Relays should be sufficient for a disconnect

Comment: Why not 8 throws worth of rf relays?

Comment: @Justme It's gigabit. The DUT is another Ethernet device (sorry, cannot give specifics) and the upstream device is a run-of-the-mill network switch.

Comment: @Bryan I'm leaning toward relays; I was hoping for something non-mechanical – but I think that might be the easiest solution. The other option here is PHYs in a repeater (back-to-back) configuration – which is a bit more complex.

Comment: A second network switch in between is not mechanical. Getting a gigabit link through standard relays can be problematic. Some devices that have failsafe bypass do use relays, but relays need to have good high frequency properties so it does not cause problems with the Ethernet link.

Comment: @foxtrot I still lean towards the rf relays but a LESS mechanical solution might be a 1:1 Ethernet transformer for each pair and a large magnet. I used to work with some powerful Nd magnets and one design had this problem where the magnet would saturate the cores of the Ethernet transformers and the signal wouldn’t get through.

Comment: Just circling back to give you an update: ended up using low-insertion-loss relays, which worked very nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make things clear: the following paragraphs only apply if you want to actually make something. You don’t **need to**. If the connection originates in a PC/Mac, you can programmatically disable the ethernet port and it’s equivalent to unplugging the cable. If the connection goes through a dumb switch, turn it off. If the connection goes through a managed switch, use the SNMP client to toggle the port enable state.

The simplest way to do it outside of the DUT is to use relays, believe it or not. Fast Ethernet works just fine through a QPST reed relay, or a couple of them side-by-side. For example, [COTO 9011-05-11](https://www.ebay.com/itm/303165911700) would be a good choice.

The way you wanted to do it requires a repeater: MAGJACK - PHY - PHY - MAGJACK. The entire repeater can be powered down, and then it acts as-if the cable was disconnected. You could cobble it together from two PHY breakout boards, e.g. look for a LAN8720 Ethernet Breakout Board.

Answer (score 2):

The Ethernet bus is supposed to have terminations at both ends of cable.

Your device adds two more so there is now four terminations.

It is unlikely to work at all.